# How does the retirement of Basic User Authentication affect SOAP integrations?

Tags: docusignapi

The messaging around DocuSign's upcoming authentication changes has been a bit confusing, especially when it comes to SOAP integrations. https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/docusign-api-basic-user-password-authentication-retirement is the most recent announcement. SOAP integrations do use Basic Authentication, which is reason to think they will be impacted by this. But the article explicitly mentions the "X-DocuSign-Authentication" header, which SOAP integrations *don't* use. But since the SOAP api only supports basic authentication (right?), I would think they would clearly say that the SOAP api is no longer supported if that's what they meant. [This recent article](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/oauth2-requirements-migration/) distinguishes between 2 different types of SOAP authentication, so is the announcement about the new method now being the only supported one?

Can I continue to use the SOAP api using App password authentication beyond October 2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the feedback! I'll pass your feedback along to see if we can clarify it to state what we mean by basic authentication. [This announcement](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/app-password-required-new-soap-integrations) may be more relevant to your use-case.

If you are using an [App Password](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/esign101/auth/app-password-authentication) (and not your DocuSign account password which you use to login to the Web UI) you will be fine to continue using it.